# Hiding a JButton

Tags: java, arrays, hide, jbutton

I'm using netbeans and I'm trying to make a button hide based on the value of an array in another class.  Basically, if the array has a value of over 0 the button should be visible. If not, it should be hidden. Any ideas? Thanks!

This is the code for the button:

```
setVisible(false);
    Total totaltab= new Total();
    totaltab.setVisible(true);
```

and this would be the array it is targeting towards, it's in a separate class.

```
   private double[][] entree = new double[][]{
    // {burgers,cheeseburgers,Veggie burgers, Fish Sandwich}
    //Sold at
    //{$4.99, $3.29, $4.50, $2.00}
    //Respectively
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {4.99, 3.29, 4.50, 2.00}
```

This is basically a project for a POS machine where the "total" button doesn't appear unless there is an active order. (e.g. the 2D array in the order class has a value greater than it's default which is 0)

Comment: This question is way too broad. What have you tried? What do you have so far? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

In your class that holds your array you need to declare a get function that returns your array.

Something like:

```
public double[][] getArray(){
    return entree;
}
```

Then in your class containing your button you will need to create an instance of the class that holds the array.

Something like:

```
ClassHoldingArray classVariable = new ClassHoldingArray();
```

Then you will be able to access your array by calling:

```
classVariable.getArray().
```

Once you have your array you can check each value and when it is at the condition you met you can set the button visible/invisible.

```
if(classVariable.getArray()[index1][index2] > 0){
    button.setVisible(true)
}
else{
    button.setVisible(false)
}
```